# How to reference current cell in Excel 2013?

Tags: excel, ms-office

I'm trying to make a spreadsheet of my company's sales by state, by month, and I'd like it to have (under any given month, for any given state), the number of orders for that month, and then in parentheses, the growth or loss percentage relative to the previous month.  For example:

```
                  February
```

```
Florida          10 (+2.75%) 

Georgia          26 (-4.27%)
```

So what formula/macros would I need to use in the cells?  Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

**What I have Now**

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you post a screenshot sample of your data set? Also can you post the efforts you made to accomplish this on your own? To receive the most effective help on SO read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You'll probably combine an [index/match](http://www.randomwok.com/excel/how-to-use-index-match/) (or vlookup) and a formula that calculates that difference, connected with `&" "&`.  But please give us some more information, as @ScottHoltzman points out.

Comment: Please tell us whether this `google-spreadsheet` or `excel`. it may make a difference.

Comment: It is currently in Google Sheets (in the picture) but I'll be using Excel, that picture is from before

Comment: I'm currently using the formula = "1 (" &LEFT(C3,4)/(B3)& ")"  but it isn't working, it says that a circular dependency is detected

Comment: @Cameron - Really? Then why is the screenshot a `google-spreadsheet`? And also, we need to see the dataset you will calculate against.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman, that picture is from before, I've since copied it all into Excel, I will update the picture now

Comment: Okay, the picture is updated, do you need any other info? @ScottHoltzman

Comment: @Cameron. Where is the data set you are calculating the monthly sales numbers for? Or are they just hard-coded in the matrix as you have it?

Comment: It'd be a lot easier if you separated each month into 2 columns: 1 for the sales value, the 2nd for the percentage.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I'm just entering them in manually from my Etsy shop statistics

Comment: @tokamak I know that, but I'm trying to avoid doing that and cluttering up the whole spreadsheet

Comment: @Cameron - you're going to have create a final table that does the calcs for you. Otherwise it will not work. If that solution is okay, let us know.

Comment: You're trying to mix data entry and formulas in the same cells. Very cumbersome. Another way to avoid dual columns is open another sheet with your data entered in, and reference those cells in this calendar that will show both the sales and percent diff.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman You mean like have a separate tab on the spreadsheet that does the calculations and then just reference those cells in the formula instead of trying to reference the one the formula is in?

Comment: @Cameron - yes, another sheet (tab) or a separate place on the existing sheet.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman awesome, thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 2):

You can create a 2nd sheet with the exact same structure as the first and enter this formula starting in C2 (for May for AL).

```
=IFERROR(Sheet1!C2&" "&TEXT((Sheet1!C2/Sheet1!B2)-1,"(+0.00%);(-0.00%)"),"NA")
```

Then drag it across rows and columns. You can make adjustments for errors and such as you need.